# Why does KB4022719 cause IE to stop printing Popups and Iframe?

Tags: printing, internet-explorer

The latest MS Rollup, KB4022719 is causing havoc with printing in IE for those that print from Popups and iframes.  I have seen many others with this problem.  I extracted the .msu and associated CAB files, and there are 564 references to ieframe.dll and ie updates.  Uninstalling the Rollup fixes it, but I was trying to see if anyone knew where I should look in the .dll files the .msu "fixes."  I am using IE 11.

IE 11 attempts to print and does, but the result of the printout is "Server Cannot Be Found."

Edit:  I cannot change the source.

Edit:  Apparently, there is a patch now.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032782/a-blank-page-or-404-error-prints-when-you-try-to-print-a-frame-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to edit your question and state that you cannot change the source - as Thom has already said, there is a source code change you can perform:

Credit to Thom on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547861/ie11-windows-7-print-issue-after-kb4021558/44574105#44574105):

```
function Print() {
  if (document.queryCommandSupported('print')) {
    document.execCommand('print', false, null);
}
else {
    window.parent.<framename>.focus();
    window.print();
}
```

If you DONT have access to the source then you are out of luck for a direct workaround -  MS also state that there is no workaround for the known problem yet: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021558/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-june-13-2017

> Known issues in this security update
>
> When you print a specific iframe or frame in a web page, the print
>   output may be blank, or text is printed that resembles the following:
>
> 404 – Not Found
>
> (A frame is a part of a web page or browser window that displays
>   content independent of its container. A frame can load content
>   independently.)
>
> This problem has also been observed in both Internet Explorer 11, and
>   in applications that host the IE Web Browser Control.
>
> There is currently no workaround for this issue. However, if you print
>   the entire web page, it will print correctly.
>
> Microsoft is researching this problem and will post more information
>   in this article when the information becomes available.

Other than that you can either CTRL+A CRTL+C CTRL+V elsewhere (MS Word/OpenOffice writer etc)and hope that will print out OK or you can right click/print preview and print (but your mileage will vary - most iframes will only print a portion this way)

The actual problem is how the temporary files interact when called to print, MS appear to have changed the storage method of calling the temporary file invoked by .print()  (source:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12349663/)

Answer (score 1):

some of our employees has issue printing from SharePoint website.
they were printing page but it was printing blank with header and footer information page 1 of 0 and res://ieframe.dll/ZmXORYC6.htm respectively.
I removed kb4021558 update from computer and it worked for me.

there is one more work around for this issue without removing KB4021558

1. Right click frame and select all
2. Right click and choose print preview.
3. there should be an option in your preview for "as selected on Screen"
   choose this allowed to print everything in the frame.

I tested both on computer and worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same issue with our 2012 R2 RDS servers and fixed it by installing the update found here https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=KB4032782

Please see [KB4032782](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032782/a-blank-page-or-404-error-prints-when-you-try-to-print-a-frame-in-ie) for more information regarding the update.

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions worked for me except adding this style to the component:

`position: isIE ? 'absolute' : 'relative'`